# How to check gitolite configuration file syntax before using it?

Tags: gitolite, syntax-checking

I would like to **check the syntax of the gitolite configuration file** `conf/gitolite.conf` before using (pushing) it. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VonC was right, one can use the `parse` function, but it is limited.

See this answer from Sitaram (Gitolite developer) to my question: 
 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitolite/-YIh7yzBI2Y

It has a little (untested) code snippet to check the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

*Before* pushing?
I don't see how.

The [`gitolite.conf` file](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/syntax.html) is parse by the [`Conf.pm#parse` function](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf.pm#L43-L80), but that happens only on the gitolite server side (where you are pushing that file).
Note on the client side (where you have only a `gitolite-admin` cloned repo)